# Application crashed after selecting contact from Contacts in android 6.0

Tags: android, android-camera

From my activity when i call Contacts to get a contact number the application  crashed. Application is running ok on other devices but when i'm try to run it in android 6.0, it crashed. i've no idea what i'm doing wrong.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

After getting the the data in `onActivityResult` method.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT) :
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c =  this.getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String contactId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String phoneNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                    Log.d(TAG, "name : "+name+" , Phone Number : "+ phoneNumber);

                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

can Anyone help me ?

Comment: Hi, please share the error log

Comment: please show this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37476222/app-crashes-due-to-java-lang-securityexception/37476285#37476285

Comment: looks like your not asking for permissions properly. In android M, you must ask for permissions in runtime. See https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: So, i need another permission related stuff implement in my application ?

Comment: hi @Evan use my code.. and follow my comment lines in my code.,, add your code,,, it works... follow comment lines inside the code....

Comment: Generally you are doing it right, but some devices like Sony Xperia Z3 don't grant temporary permission for CONTACT_READ, opposed to what documentation says [Select a contact](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Contacts). What kind of android phone are you developing for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From android 6.0 (Mashmello) , android has introduced [Run Time Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for users to grand permission to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. So, Your calling should be like this ->

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    /*If Android M*/
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SendMoneyByDetailsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        /*If Android M and Not permission granted */
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SendMoneyByDetailsActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
    } else {
        /*If Android M and permission granted */
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
    }
} else {
    /*IF not Android M*/
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
}
```

And when user grant the permission then you can call the intent to pick contact list ->

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //permission was granted, yay! Do the
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
            } else {
                // permission denied
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And don't forgot to add permission in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: I will try your code let your know that it's working or not .

Comment: You welcome. Follow the link i've given to my answer. In future it will help you other run time permission related stuff.

Answer (score 3):

All of the answers here are wrong. You shouldn't need `READ_CONTACT` permission at all to retrieve single contact using `ACTION_PICK` intent. You should be granted this permission temporary to be able to retrieve contact specific data. However there are some devices that don't implement this API in a good way. Myself I have found Sony Xperia Z3, but I heard about HTC devices also had this problem.

> To have the user select a contact and provide your app access to all the contact information, use the ACTION_PICK action and specify the MIME type to Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE.
>
> The result Intent delivered to your onActivityResult() callback contains the content: URI pointing to the selected contact. **The response grants your app temporary permissions to read that contact using the Contacts Provider API even if your app does not include the READ_CONTACTS permission.**

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Contacts

**[UPDATE]**

After upgrading Sony Xperia Z3 system image to version `23.5.A.1.291` bug does not occur anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is permission issue

add bellow permission inside manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

accept permissions in marshmallows

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

actual implementation

add bellow code inside Main Activity
call `checkAndAddPermission()` method inside `onCreate()` method

```
final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 1244;

   private void checkAndAddPermission() {
       List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

       final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<>();
       if (!addPermission(permissionsList, android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS))
           permissionsNeeded.add("ReadContacts");

       if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
           if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {
               // Need Rationale
               String message = "You need to grant access to " + permissionsNeeded.get(0);
               for (int i = 1; i < permissionsNeeded.size(); i++)
                   message = message + ", " + permissionsNeeded.get(i);

               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                       REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
           } else {
               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                       REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
           }
       }

   }

   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
   private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
       if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           permissionsList.add(permission);
           // Check for Rationale Option
           if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission))
               return false;
       }
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
       switch (requestCode) {
           case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {
               Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();
               // Initial
               perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
               // Fill with results
               for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                   perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
               // Check for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
               if (perms.get(android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                   // All Permissions Granted
               } else {
                   // Permission Denied
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Some Permission is Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                           .show();
               }
           }
           break;
           default:
               super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
       }
   }
```

Comment: Already added permission in my manifest file. Can you share some code to clear about the permissions in marshmallows thing.

Comment: check link given in answer, you need to accept permissions runtime

Answer (score 0):

It not your manifest problem its problem with android 6.0 it requires **[Runtime Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)**... 
after adding this in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Just change your code to this In your code..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = 001;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        //give here permissions what ever you want...
        // if you are using one add only one... not all..

        if ((CheckPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS))&&
             (CheckPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE))&&
             (CheckPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET))&&
             (CheckPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE))&&
             (CheckPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE)))
        {
            PermHandling();
        }

        //now reqest runtime permissions..

        else {
            RequestPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS);
            RequestPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS );
            RequestPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS );
            RequestPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS );
            RequestPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS );

        }

    }
    private void PermHandling() {
        //Your app internal parts....
        //Here your stuff works...
    }

    //private void NewPermHandling(){

    //}

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

        switch (permsRequestCode) {

            case REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    PermHandling();
                } else {
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "Please Grant Permissions other wise app will close.!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void RequestPermission(Activity thisActivity, String Permission, int Code) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Permission)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
                    Permission)) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                        new String[]{Permission},
                        Code);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean CheckPermission(Context context, String Permission) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I also faced same problem my applications worked on till 5.1 but 6.0+ due to Runtime permissions We need to add them.. and accept those permissions at runtime

Comment: Why so many permission ? i'm not using internet . So, should i also need that ?

Comment: in code at comment I mentioned at ` //give here permissions what ever you want...` what ever you want give them like read contacts... if you have only one remove other in if and else ...

Comment: If you have one permission add one... if there are more add all of them in if and else.... those are requestd at run time they are more possible occur in feature at android M and N...